# Calculate total of dynamic values of readonly inputs. Jquery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I have my form pretty much done and I need to calculate the total values of input fields after AJAX fills them based on user selects.  I have tried and tried and tried to find a solution but nothing is working... ugh.

Here's the html for the input fields that need to be calculated  and the field that the sum needs to be returned to:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control prices" id="lt1total" placeholder="Amount" value="" readonly>
<input type="text" class="form-control prices" id="lt2total" placeholder="Amount" value="" readonly>
<input type="text" class="form-control prices" id="lt3total" placeholder="Amount" value="" readonly>

<input type="text" class="form-control disabled" id="lttotal" placeholder="Amount" value="" readonly>
```

Here is the AJAX request (there is one for each they all work correctly):

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'example.url',
        data: {
            lt1datetype: lt1datetype,
            lt1tt: lt1tt,
        }
    }).done(function(result) {
        console.log('', result);
        $('#lt1total').val(result);
    });
```

And this is the only jquery function that I have gotten to even put a value for #lttotal :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".prices").each(function(){
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $("#lttotal").val(sum);
});
```

It only outputs 0 for the amount.  The values that AJAX is getting are like this 123.00 or 1234.00  I'm stuck and aggravated.  Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does *"there is one for each"* mean? If you make a request for each input then you will need to run calculation code after all requests are done to do the totals. Not really clear without clarification

Comment: There is an AJAX request for each amount generated for each lift ticket.  So to get the #lt1total there is an AJAX request to the database to extract a field value based on user input and populated into value of #lt1total.  There is one for each #lt1total, #lt2total, #lt3total.

Comment: So I ended up just making an update total button and binding the function to a .click and a checkbox on change before the user can hit the submit button.  Thank you all anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to run the calculations code after all the requests have been completed.

```
var request1 = $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'example.url',
        data: {...}
    }).done(function(result) {
        console.log('', result);
        $('#lt1total').val(result);
    });

var request2 = $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'example.url',
        data: {...}
        }
    }).done(function(result) {
        console.log('', result);
        $('#lt2total').val(result);
    });

$.when(request1, request2....., requestn).done(function(){
    // set totals here instead of on page load
})
```